# Trouble displaying meaningful error message on webpage

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, web-config

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug ="true" targetFramework="2.0"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
```

I'm trying to get some type of meaningful error message instead of some generic HTTP 500 error message. Usually when I set customErrors to off on my other, not related to this webpage that is giving me trouble, it usually produce a meaningful error message on my other apps.

Also this page was created in classic asp.

Comment: Does this answer help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459724/how-to-remove-error-messages-iis7/4460680#4460680

Comment: It's something but unfortunately didn't work =(

Answer (score 0):

Classic ASP doesn't use web.config AFAIK (I've always used IIS anyway).

In IIS7, select your site, double click the "ASP" module, expand "Debugging Properties" then set "Send Errors to Browser" to True.