# Laravel 4 on IIS7 not working

Tags: php, iis-7, laravel

I am developing and learning laravel on my local host running wamp. Everything works fine on local host, but when i copy everything to my shared IIS7 host i get an Internal server error.

Everything works fine untill `$app->boot();` in 'vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\start.php'.

I tried giving all folders all permissions but that didn't solve the problem.

I don't have composer installed on my shared host, because i believe i could just copy all the code from my local host, to the shared host, and only had to convert the .htaccess to Web.config (and these files work like they should). This worked when i was working with CodeIgniter, and everything was just copy/paste.

Does anyone know what is wrong and how i can solve this?

Comment: Can you add a web.config file to the root of your site and add the XML described in my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459724/how-to-remove-error-messages-iis7/4460680#4460680 - that should let you see the underlying PHP error.

Comment: ErrorException
session_start() [<a href='function.session-start'>function.session-start</a>]: open(....\app\storage/sessions\sess_skd54mp2j25l70rqabpt0oen35, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13)

Comment: Had a look into this errer and solved the problem. I changed the rights using my FTP client which probably did not change it at all.
After changing the rights using my hosters webpanel, laravel worked as intended.

Comment: Cool, glad that helped. By default IIS7 will hide upstream 500 errors (from ASP, PHP, .NET etc). Dropping in that blob of xml config will force it to pass them through. In production just comment out that config to prevent possibly useful error info leaking to miscreants. Also did you know that you can answer your own question and mark it as accepted?