# Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\phpMyAdmin\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc on line 177 on IIS 8

Tags: php, mysql, iis, phpmyadmin

I have been trying to setup phpMyAdmin on IIS 8 (running on Windows 8) to work with MySQL. I have downloaded the English version from the website, and extracted the main files to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\phpMyAdmin. Whenever I try to launch the configuration page from localhost, I get the follow error:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\phpMyAdmin\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc on line 177`

I have tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22271260/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mb-detect-encoding-in-c-apache-htdocs), and while that does allow me to access phpMyAdmin, I get an error 500 on one of my pages which has just a basic php / html form on it.

I am using php 5.4.30 and phpMyAdmin 4.2.6.

Comment: So adding the mbstring extension, solved your phpMyAdmin problem?

Comment: @MarcDelisle Yes, I was able to access phpMyAdmin after that. The problem is that I was no longer able to access one of my pages, all it did is return an error 500. I ended up having to reinstall PHP to get it back (at the loss of phpMyAdmin).

Comment: Re-enable mb_string again in your `php.ini` file to get PHPMyAdmin working again. Then, where ever the root of your PHP app's site is add a `web.config` file and follow the instructions here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4460680/419 - that will force IIS to render the underlying error. Tell us what you see.

Comment: @K̨̩̭͚̘̗̻̞͈͖̙͙e̗̦̼̳̣̦͜͡v̢̝̟̗̱̯͉ I added `<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />` to my `web.config` file, but all that happens is I get an error 500 from my browser, instead of the IIS error 500 page ([screenshot](http://puu.sh/aBKUD/6392fbcd4d.png))

Comment: @grahamhoyes - turn off "Show friendly HTTP error messages" in your browser's Advanced settings (or switch to Google chrome or Firefox).

Comment: @K̨̩̭͚̘̗̻̞͈͖̙͙e̗̦̼̳̣̦͜͡v̢̝̟̗̱̯͉ Actually, I seem to have a working fix using the php.ini file from Xampp. I'm going to try to figure out what is going on, then write an answer. Thanks for the suggestions though :)